# how to get browser history in android Version above lollipop

Tags: android, browser-history

I am trying to get the all visited website on browser on android phone.
**I have tried the following code-**

```
val BOOKMARKS_URI = Uri.parse("content://browser/bookmarks")
    val HISTORY_PROJECTION = arrayOf(
        "_id", // 0
        "url", // 1
        "visits", // 2
        "date", // 3
        "bookmark", // 4
        "title", // 5
        "favicon", // 6
        "thumbnail", // 7
        "touch_icon", // 8
        "user_entered"// 9
    )

    val mCur = this.managedQuery(BOOKMARKS_URI, HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null)
    this.startManagingCursor(mCur)
    mCur.moveToFirst()

    var title = ""
    var url = ""
    var date = ""

    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.count > 0) {
        while (!mCur.isLast) {

            title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("title"))
            url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("url"))
            date = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("date"))

            Log.d("BrowserHistory" + mCur.count, "$title *** $url *** $date")

            mCur.moveToNext()
        }
    }
```

This always getting zero size of cursor in all condition.

Comment: "I am trying to get the all visited website on browser on android phone" -- that is not possible in general, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: did you found any solution?